# zf scaffolding tools

Tags: zend-framework, zend-framework2

Are there any open source projects any of you would recommend to follow or contribute toward, including those already documented among the zf contributors, to add zend framework scaffolding of crud functionality for rapid development as found in most competitors frameworks?

As a contributor of not only the language and framework, but also as a user of zf on a daily basis, I know this is a topic of interest and I feel professional developers like you would find here would have something to contribute toward my question and finding a library that is underway that can be contributed to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, apparently this is not an appropriate question to ask, i've learned, at stackoverflow.  Didn't realize this kind of question wasn't allowed since it doesn't have code I guess.

Answer (score 1):

Still pointing out one Repo that generates a new module with folder structure, config and module class

- [Inforbiro / ZF2-Code-Generator](https://github.com/Inforbiro/ZF2-Code-Generator)

While personally i feel this to be more troublesome than doing it by hand, it's a first step only. Though it appears development already has stopped, for now.

If ever (and i'm pretty sure) there will be a ZF2-Tool, you'll find it at the zf-commons repository

- [ZF-Commons](https://github.com/zf-commons)

Comment: You should check out how some of the other frameworks that do this, because it saves a lot of time and I really wish ZF had this.  From a simple model, you can generate every file associated with and needed to implement CRUD functionality.